# use a object of a fragment in another fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I got a fragment, where I'm receiving messages, which a written into a message object `demoRxMsg`

In the receiver thread I call `demoRxMsg = new MessageStructure();` data is received and written, everything is fine.

Now I want to use this `demoRxMsg` in another Fragment, to read out the containing data and "convert" them into a nice UI element.

The Question is: How do I do this. I tried to write a Getter, but when I call it via

```
demoRxMsg = ((Diagnostics) getActivity()).getMessage();
```

I get `Cannot cast from Activity to Diagnostics`.
Is it because a Fragment is not an Activity? But the Fragment (as I understood the fragment tutorials) is part of the activity, isn't it ?

I hope someone can help :)

Comment: the type is MessageStructure, its a custom class

Comment: In this case it says: getMessage() is undefined for the type Activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragment is not an activity, it's a part of activity means they work together, without activity, fragment won't work etc.

If you want to use your data in another fragment you need to use Bundle

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("my_data",YourData);

YourFragment f = new YourFragment();
f.setArguments(b);
```

And in your fragment to get value,

```
Bundle b = getArguments();
int v = b.getInt("my_data",0);
```

if it's an object that you want to pass, you need to serialize it and deserialize in fragment again

Comment: like this: b.putInt ("message", demoRxMsg); ?

Comment: int was an example, if type of demoRxMsg is int, yes you can do it like that, otherwise you need to appropriate type, if it's a custom class that you made, you need to use parcelable

Comment: The method putParcelable(String, Parcelable) in the type Bundle is not applicable for the arguments (String, MessageStructure)

Comment: Maybe to add, MessageStructure contains 6 variables: 3 times byte, 1 int, one int[], and one long ... do I have to "put" every variable in a single step? I think the problem is the whole MessageStructure

Comment: Check this out for parcelable, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Answer (score 0):

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelableArrayList(key, value)// The value arrayList object must be a parcel able object
    fm = getFragmentManager();
    if (fm != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        frag.setArguments(bundle);
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_main_container, frag, tag);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

Comment: The method putParcelable(String, Parcelable) in the type Bundle is not applicable for the arguments (String, MessageStructure). A Cast is not able.

Comment: putParcelableArrayList() is used to tranfer an arrayList of custom objects.